# Turn Page scrolling with Arrows off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

If your building a game or interactive website and want to use the arrow keys as a page function. (e.g. having something on the screen move)

Is it possible to disable page scrolling via the arrow keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(Event) {
        if(Event.which == 38 || Event.which == 40) {
            Event.preventDefault();
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged jQuery in your question, I'll provide a jQuery solution.

Essentially, you need to capture the key that was used, and then use the `preventDefault()` method on the event. This will stop the browser scrolling when the arrow keys are pressed. Here's a jsFiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/KMeGc/

And here's the jQuery code for your reference:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40)
       e.preventDefault(); 

    switch(key)
    {
        case 37:
            // Code to run for left arrow key here...
            break;

        case 38:
            // Code to run for up arrow key here...
            break;

        case 39:
            // Code to run for right arrow key here...
            break;

        case 40:
            // Code to run for down arrow key here...
            break;
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).keydown(function(ev){
    // check the arrow keycodes here
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```